Python module 'functools' error after upgrading gcloud components
After upgrading gcloud components (gcloud components update) I see the following error: AttributeError: module 'functools' has no attribute 'cache' when trying to run 'dev_appserver.py'. I've since downgraded back to 435.0.1:
Your current Google Cloud CLI version is: 472.0.0
You will be upgraded to version: 435.0.1
My operating environment is Ubuntu 20:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-177-generic x86_64)
When I run dev_appserver.py I am seeing the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ml/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/ml/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 99, in _run_file
    _execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/home/ml/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 81, in _execfile
    exec(open(fn).read(), scope)
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "/home/ml/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/request_info.py", line 33, in <module>
    from google.appengine.runtime import context
  File "/home/ml/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/context/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    @functools.cache
AttributeError: module 'functools' has no attribute 'cache'


recently there were some issues with python version in your environment and the version gcloud requires, check their installation page and find the version that'll work with your python version

I'm running Python 3.8.10, the current version for my platform. It does not make sense to me that I would have to deviate from that in order for the gcloud upgrade to function properly(?)
